# How to change value of the NSTextField instantly as we type?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift

There are two outlets connected to my ViewController.swift file.

```
@IBOutlet var myOutlet: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet var yourOutlet: NSTextField!
```

There is an action connected too.

```
@IBAction func myAction(sender: NSTextField) {
    self.yourOutlet.doubleValue = myOutlet.doubleValue - 10
```

When i run the app, it works. 
I enter 15 to text field that myOutlet connected, then hit the enter. And field that yourOutlet connected, takes the value of 5.

If there is no enter button needed, it would be better. So how to make the value change instantly, as we type?

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I did not get a chance to do swift and OSX development, but I can lead you to the solution.

Take a look at [textDidChange(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextField/textDidChange:)

> Posts a notification that the text has changed and forwards this
>   message to the receiver’s cell if it responds.
>
> **Declaration**
>
> `func textDidChange(_ aNotification: NSNotification)`
>   Parameters aNotification   The `NSControlTextDidChangeNotification`
>   notification that is posted to the default notification center.
>   Discussion This method causes the receiver’s delegate to receive a
>   controlTextDidChange: message. See the NSControl class specification
>   for more information on the text delegate method.

So to achieve your goal, you would implement this delegate, it will get called each time you edit the text inside of the `NSTextField`.Then inside of that delegate block you will provide the logic needed.

Comment: Thanks for that great answer. But because of i'm beginner, couldn't figure out to use that method.

When i use that only `@IBAction func brutAct(sender: NSTextField) {
        if NSControlTextDidChangeNotification == true {
            self.kdvOut.doubleValue = brutOut.doubleValue + 1.0
        }`

it doesn't work.
if i create a method like this, and try to use that:

`func textDidChange(myNotification: NSNotification){
            NSControlTextDidChangeNotification == true`

Nothing happens either :(

Comment: Actually, that's the delegate for a text *view*. Since a text *field* is a control, it sends `controlTextDidChange(_:)` to its delegate.

Comment: To use the delegate method, first connect the `delegate` outlet of the text field to your controller. You don't compare `NSControlTextDidChangeNotification` to `true`. You might compare `myNotification.name` to `NSControlTextDidChangeNotification`, but it's not necessary since that method should only be called for that notification. Just do something like `func controlTextDidChange(myNotification: NSNotification) {  self.kdvOut.doubleValue = brutOut.doubleValue + 1.0 }`.

Comment: Thank you @Ken but did i miss something? It still not working:
http://imgur.com/07YCrMW

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like your outlets are not connected. The little circles in the left margin are not filled. Although that may be a change or bug in the most recent builds of Xcode. Since I would expect Swift to cause a crash if the method were called when those outlets were `nil`, I'm thinking it's not being called. You can put a log statement in it to be sure. Have you connect the `delegate` outlet of the "brut" text field to the view controller?